# Input Field to force no spaces and all downcase

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I use Devise and changed the routes so that the Users Profile uses :name in the url instead of :id.

so i have `http://localhost:3000/users/testuser`

The problem is that when a user Registers on the site, the `:name` Input field allows them to use spaces and Uppercase letters.

How can i set up the input so the user `DONT EVEN have the ability to use spaces or Upcase Letters`.

Meaning that when he hits space, nothing happens in the input..

If it helps, my input field code is:

```
 <!-- Username Input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Username</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.input :name, :autofocus => true, label: false %>
    <%= f.hint 'No Spaces, all downcase please' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using rails you can use [client side validation](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations)

Or
Use [JQuery validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation)

It has nice documentation. you can implement any kinda custom validations there.